# Question | Visual Studio Code Editor .cshtml file not working properly

Tags: .net, visual-studio, razor

I'm trying to create small app on .Net but i faced problem while working on .cshtml file.
On this file, I cant format doccument and my property names not come automatically. For instance, ProductPrice not come.

[image: VS2022]

This is my settings but not sure am i wrong with this ?
[image]

Note: My Visual Studio 2022 also not recognize Razor syntax

[image: VS2022]

I waste my 1hour to find any solution but cant find anything. Do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing these extensions https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/updated-razor-support-in-visual-studio-code-now-with-blazor-support maybe this could help.